# SSHJ Java Library - set cipher suit for SFTP connection

Tags: ssh, sftp, sshj

We are using SSHJ library for connecting to SFTP server using SSHv2. While connecting to the server we get below Negotiated algorithms:

```
net.schmizz.sshj.transport.KeyExchanger:234 - Negotiated algorithms: [ kex=diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256; sig=ssh-rsa; c2sCipher=aes128-cbc; s2cCipher=aes128-cbc; c2sMAC=hmac-sha1; s2cMAC=hmac-sha1; c2sComp=none; s2cComp=none; rsaSHA2Support=false ]
```

Our Requirement is to set the Cipher to AEAD_AES_x_GCM
x=256,128 or AESx-CTR with HMAC-SHA2-y
x=256,192,128 and y=512,256 . I tried to set the cipher through below implementation:

```
Config config = new DefaultConfig();
            config.setCipherFactories(initCipherFactories());
            SSHClient client = new SSHClient(config);

protected List<Factory.Named<Cipher>> initCipherFactories() {
        List<Factory.Named<Cipher>> avail = new LinkedList<>(
                Arrays.asList(new AES256CTR.Factory(), new AES256CBC.Factory()));
        boolean warn = false;
        // Ref. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SSHD-24
        // "AES256 and AES192 requires unlimited cryptography extension"
        for (Iterator<Factory.Named<Cipher>> i = avail.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            final Factory.Named<Cipher> f = i.next();
            try {
                final Cipher c = f.create();
                final byte[] key = new byte[c.getBlockSize()];
                final byte[] iv = new byte[c.getIVSize()];
                c.init(Cipher.Mode.Encrypt, key, iv);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                warn = true;
                i.remove();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (warn)
            log.warn("Disabling high-strength ciphers: cipher strengths apparently limited by JCE policy");

        return avail;
    }
```

Can you tell me `new AES256CTR.Factory(), new AES256CBC.Factory()` these are deprecated in SSHJ library so what is came in place of this?

Comment: Ended up by using BlockCiphers.AES256CTR()

Comment: Remember that answering your own question is totally allowed and encouraged and provides other users valuable information. So if you can, please create an informative answer for your own question, maybe with example of how you resolved the issue so that it would better serve other users with similar problem.